In Re:monster, why are goblins and orcs two different creatures?
Aren't goblins and orcs supposed to be the same creature or two different creatures?
Because according to my research, "orc" is supposed to mean "goblin" in the Elven language (from "The Hobbit" and "Lord of the Rings")?
If they are usually the same creature, why are they two different creatures in "Re:monster"?
Goblins:

Orcs:


Because they are not usually the same creature and are generally considered different. In most anime/manga you will find that goblins are generally smaller weaker creatures and orcs are larger and stronger.

@Henkyo it seems like a pretty common theme in anime/manga that they are different creatures which will impact voting.

They're imaginary creatures, so no one can define whether they are different or the same.  Hence, any writer can go either way.
